# mpi process exitting on signal 11

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, mpi, distributed-computing

I have an simple mpi program for performing MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather. It takes in as argument number of elements to be sent to each process and then performs average of random numbers on different processes using  MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather.

```
float *create_rand_nums(int num_elements){
    float *rand_nums = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * num_elements);
    assert(rand_nums != NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < num_elements; i++){
        *(rand_nums+i) = (rand()/ (float)RAND_MAX);
        printf("Create_rand_nums func val %f \n", *(rand_nums+i));
        //printf("Create_rand_nums func address %f \n", (rand_nums+i));
    }
    return rand_nums;
}

// Computes the average of an array of numbers
float compute_avg(float *array, int num_elements){
    float sum = 0.f;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum / num_elements;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: avg num_elements_per_proc\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int num_elements_per_proc = atoi(argv[0]);
  // Seed the random number generator to get different results each time
  srand(time(NULL));

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); 
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // Create a random array of elements on the root process. Its total
  // size will be the number of elements per process times the number of processes
  float *rand_nums = NULL;
  if (world_rank == 0){
   rand_nums = create_rand_nums(num_elements_per_proc * world_size);
  }

  // For each process, create a buffer that will hold a subset of the entire array
  float *sub_rand_nums = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * num_elements_per_proc);
  assert(sub_rand_nums != NULL);

  // Scatter the random numbers from the root process to all processes in the MPI world
  MPI_Scatter(rand_nums, num_elements_per_proc, MPI_FLOAT, sub_rand_nums, num_elements_per_proc, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  // Compute the average of your subset
  float sub_avg = compute_avg(sub_rand_nums, num_elements_per_proc);
  int i;
  printf("Avg inside %f \n", sub_avg);

  // Gather all partial averages down to the root process
  float *sub_avgs = NULL;
  if (world_rank == 0) {
    sub_avgs = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * world_size);
    assert(sub_avgs != NULL);
  }
  MPI_Gather(&sub_avg, 1, MPI_FLOAT, sub_avgs, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for (i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {
        printf("Avg %f \n", *(sub_avgs+i));
    }

  // Now that we have all of the partial averages on the root, compute the
  // total average of all numbers. Since we are assuming each process computed
  // an average across an equal amount of elements, this computation will
  // produce the correct answer.
  if (world_rank == 0) {
    float avg = compute_avg(sub_avgs, world_size);
    printf("Avg of all elements is %f\n", avg);
    // Compute the average across the original data for comparison
    float original_data_avg =
      compute_avg(rand_nums, num_elements_per_proc * world_size);
    printf("Avg computed across original data is %f\n", original_data_avg);

  }



// Clean up
  if (world_rank == 0) {
    free(rand_nums);
    free(sub_avgs);
  }
  free(sub_rand_nums);

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

On running this code, I am getting :

> > mpicc -o MPI_Scatter_MPI_Gather MPI_Scatter_MPI_Gather.cc
> >
> > mpirun --oversubscribe -host localhost -np 4 ./MPI_Scatter_MPI_Gather 2

```
Avg inside nan 
Avg inside nan 
Avg inside nan 
Avg inside nan 
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** Process received signal ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Failing at address: 0x0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff50b65f5a _sigtramp + 26
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 2] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff508e5145 start + 1
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 3] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** End of error message ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** Process received signal ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Failing at address: 0x0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 3 with PID 0 on node dhcp-10-142-194-10 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
7fff50b65f5a _sigtramp + 26
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 2] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff508e5145 start + 1
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 3] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** End of error message ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** Process received signal ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Failing at address: 0x0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff50b65f5a _sigtramp + 26
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 2] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff508e5145 start + 1
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 3] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** End of error message ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** Process received signal ***
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Signal code:  (0)
[dhcp-10-142-19] Failing at address: 0x0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff50b65f5a _sigtramp + 26
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 2] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff508e5145 start + 1
[dhcp-10-142-19] [ 3] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
[dhcp-10-142-19] *** End of error message ***
```

I want to run this program first on 1 machine with 2 core and then on multiple machines. But it is failing even on a single machine. Please help

Comment: `atoi(argv1])` and only print `sub_avgs` on rank `0`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [Gilles Gouaillardet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041112/mpi-process-exitting-on-signal-11/58595536#comment102483437_58041112), `atoi(argv[0])` is badly-formed, and `sub-avgs` should only be printed on rank 0.